# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 WHILE LOOP

Tags: java, csv, while-loop

I am trying to read a big csv file in a while loop.
But when I run the code I got `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5`
Is there a step I am missing?

```
  String csvFileToRead = "C:/automation/test.csv"; 

  BufferedReader br = null; 

  String line = "";  
  String splitBy = ",";  

  try {  boolean firstLine = true;
      br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileToRead));  

      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null ) {       

       if (firstLine) {
           firstLine = false;
                continue;}

       String[] id = line.split(splitBy);
    String replace = id[5].replace("\"", "");



    String cardNo = id[5].replace("\"", "");


    String fname = id[8].replace("\"", "");
    String name = driver.findElement(By.id("bnxczxc")).getAttribute("value");


    if (name.equals(fname)) { 
        //code
    }
    else {
        //code
    }


   }  

  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
  } catch (IOException e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
  } finally {  
   if (br != null) {  
    try {  
     br.close();   

    }
    catch (IOException e) {  
     e.printStackTrace();}}}
```

Comment: Some of you content of the file might not have that much commas as you have coded.Show us the content of the file

Answer (score 1):

You're eventually hitting a line in your CSV file that doesn't have at least 6 values in it, so this line is throwing an error:

```
String replace = id[5].replace("\"", "");
```

I would suggest a check such as:

```
if(id.length > 0)
{
// Do the stuff you're trying to do
}
else
{
// Log or print error
}
```

What I expect you'll find if you troubleshoot further is that your program is attempting to read the last line of the file which would be blank.

Answer (score 0):

You get the exception here `id[5]` if your line has only 4 attributes. Check `id.length` before you try to get the 5th attribute. And remember that arrays are zero beased in java.

Answer (score 0):

When you are specifying array index like id[5], there is the exception because id array doesn't contain elements till index 5. If the size of id array is 5, then you have to access its last element by using id[4] as array length starts from 0. 
PS: First System.out.println(id.length) to check the length of id array. Then you will have the overall idea of this exception.

Hope it may help.